# How to delete such kind of two dimension array?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

```
    #define NB -3
    #define NM -2
    #define NS -1
    #define ZO 0
    #define PS 1
    #define PM 2
    #define PB 3


 int (*rule)[7] =new int[7][7]{{NB,NB,NM,NM,NS,ZO,ZO},
                              {NB,NB,NM,NS,NS,ZO,PS},
                              {NM,NM,NM,NS,ZO,PS,PS},
                              {NM,NM,NS,ZO,PS,PM,PM},
                              {NS,NS,ZO,PS,PS,PM,PM},
                              {NS,ZO,PS,PM,PM,PM,PB},
                              {ZO,ZO,PM,PM,PM,PB,PB}};
```

should I use the following method?

```
for(int i=0;i<7;++i)
{
   delete[] rule++;
}
```

Or if I use `delete[] rule`, it seems weird becuse the underlying object is an array of arrrays, but not array of pointers, which is the type of `rule`.

Comment: You only used `new` once, so you should only use `delete` once; as in `delete[] rule`.

Comment: you should use a `std::vector` or `std::array` and stay away from such pointer madness

Comment: The downvotes are harsh. I don't see this as obvious. Apart from all the `#define`s, this is nicely written.

Comment: @user463035818 I was using cpp in an embeded platform, which does not support `vector`  etc.

Comment: @Bathsheba not my DV, but a reason could be because there is no research showing, which is one of the tooltip reasons of the DV button. For the same reason, I'm unsure about the upvotes for this question.

Comment: @Default: It's quite hard to research this, unless you already know the answer.

Comment: @Default I was asking this question not just for the right answer, but for the underlying reason or mechanism from perspective of language.

Comment: @Bathsheba there are [a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=delete+two+dimensional+array+c%2B%2B+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

`rule` is an array of pointers to type `int[7]`.

The former was declared with a `new[]`.

Therefore you need to use `delete[] rule;` to release the memory.

Comment: But `delete[] rule` seems like deleting array of pointers. The real objcet is array of array. Does `delete[] rule` make sense?

Comment: @bigxiao: Indeed it does. The rule is surprisingly simple: pair `new` with `delete`, and pair `new[]` with `delete[]`.